# Integrate C++ in Cordova electron

Tags: windows, cordova, electron, cordova-plugins, desktop-application

As we all know Cordova has added electron platform to build desktop apps for different Operating Systems. Like we can integrate C++ in android using JNI and Objective C wrappers for iOS and mac OSX. Is that possible to do something similar in Cordova's electron platform and windows platforms.

Followed references
[1](https://pspdfkit.com/blog/2018/running-native-code-in-electron-and-the-case-for-webassembly/)
[2](https://gauriatiq.medium.com/electron-app-with-c-back-end-as-native-addon-napi-c67867f4058)
Those references didn't helped me incase of Cordova project.

Can someone help me with this. Thank you for your time and response.

Answer (score 0):

There is Webview https://github.com/webview/webview , which can help to build GUIs similar to electron but with c++. It is using HTML / CSS / JS as UI layer.
The old version was header only but didn't run on msvc c++. The new version runs on msvc but is more complicate.

There also is Nimview https://github.com/marcomq/nimview, which uses an older version of webview and already has some C++ / msvc examples. It improves testing, debugging and development for offline applications, compared to webview.
Nimview can also be used for Android.

Disclaimer:
I'm the author of Nimview